# Adding new chars to a fixed char in Arduino

Tags: c, char, int, arduino, lan

I have following code:

```
   char page[] PROGMEM =
"HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
"Retry-After: 600\r\n"
"\r\n"
"<html>"
  "<head><title>"
    "DeckTone Server"
  "</title></head>"
  "<body>"
    "<h3>Start page</h3>"
    "<p>"
      "Arduino UNO .<br />"
      "Autor: DeckTone."
    "</p>"
  "</body>"
"</html>"
;
```

and i have following integer:

```
int a=2;
```

my char on webserver on arduino is serving following code:

```
  if (ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive())) {
    memcpy_P(ether.tcpOffset(), page, sizeof page);
    ether.httpServerReply(sizeof page - 1);
    memcpy_P(ether.tcpOffset(), page2, sizeof page2);
    ether.httpServerReply(sizeof page2 - 1);
  }
```

I would want to add following integer a (in future other variables too) to the char so the following code would post a integer included in this page char. Example with my char will be very helpfull.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you, after all, talking about `snprintf()` (google it)?

Comment: Yes!  But I thought it was sprintf().  Is snprintf() better?

Comment: I'm making code on arduino, so I don't think there would be cstdio.h library. What i want? I want to add variables to char table, where some data is already on that table (like in code).

Comment: @Jim It's safer. `sprintf()` is insecure and it has practically no legitimate use case.

Comment: @Jim It's important to realize why `sprintf()` is insecure. It has no limit on how much will be printed in to the buffer, and so it allows for buffer overflow, `snprintf()` lets you send in the size and won't print past the size, so it is safe from buffer overflow. E.g. `char buf[2]; sprintf(buf, "%d", 1);` is ok, `buf[0]` is `'1'` and `buf[1]` is `'\0'`, but if I did `sprintf(buf, "%d", 999)` it'll be writing beyond the end of my array, a very destructive behaviour.

Comment: @DeckTone, You could do it manually by pasting portions of the string together, adding the integer string value as needed.  It looks like you have 4 string segments pasted together with 3 occurances of the page value.

Comment: So could somebody give me example with first part of the code, where the variable is added to the char page?

Comment: Stuff that doesn't check also runs faster, so if you know you will be safe, then sprintf() can be OK.  I'm not disagreeing with you, but at the end of the day, there can be a cost to adding training wheels to every part of one's code.

Comment: snprintf(strng,"Value is num%d and more words here",pagno);  (something like this...?)

Comment: Jim but how can I add the string to string segments? (On Arduino there are not as many libraries as in pure C)

Comment: @Jim Nah, it's just that you probably don't realize that premature optimization is evil.

Comment: Decktone, do you have strcat?

Comment: H2CO3, most of design rules is premature optimization.....

Comment: Decktone, you have concat().  Build the final string with a series of calls to concat(). For the integer value, you have to convert it to a string.  (And check that the final string size doesn't overrun everything...)

Answer (score 0):

Since char page[] creates a fixed char with elements +1 (for the terminator) you can not easely add something to it. You could design a fixed size array sufficient to take additional data and fit your speciic hardware (For the wise guys I counted his example text and added 100 because he wanted to add some variables) on OPs HW (Flash memory on UNO 32k bytes (of which .5k is used for the bootloader)

```
    char page[320 + 100]
```

for an ESP8266 /ESP32 (Flash memory starting with 1MB usually 4Mb you could take

```
    char page[4048]
```

and then operate on that.

Comment: I perfectly understand what storing in flash memory means, I would know no web capable Arduino where 4kb would be a problem  but I edited to be more precise